# RegExp with global multiline infinite matches

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok so i was trying to match all lines and obtain the string index of the matches but i ran into a weird issue

```
var string = 'a\n',
    regexp = /^.*$/gim;
```

if you run

```
regexp.exec(string);
```

It will eventually match "" infinitely, why? The reason i ask is because its common for people to perform these type of matches in a while loop and this will produce an infinite loop unless you are ensuring that the previous match index is not the current index.

**Edit**
so the solution to my issue required me doing

```
while (match = regexp.exec(string)) {
    if (!match[0].length) {
        regexp.lastIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.*` matches a zero-length string. At the end of the string, it can always match this again.

Comment: So are you saying that internally javascript is performing this lastIndex check when running this type of match `'a\nb\n'.match(/^.*$/gim)`

Comment: Is there a reason why `exec` doesn't perform this task on its own, it seems like unexpected behavior.

Comment: I guess because it's more primitive, and leaves it up to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

It's matching the end of the string. When the `m` flag is used, `^` equals the start of a line... and you got a new line at the end, and the `lastIndex` (the value that's used to start the search from) won't move from that, because it matched an empty string.

To better understand this, try using this:

```
var string = "a\n\n\b\n";
```

It will never match "b" either.

Answer (score 0):

Your string variable has 2 NEWLINE characters, resulting in a 3 line string

```
a
b
<<an empty line>>
```

Your RegEx states that you're searching for strings that matches entire lines, `.*` means any character 0 or more times

Since an empty line matches that `.*` Regex, you'll end up with the empty string as result.

Comment: He understands why it matches the empty line the first time. His question is why it doesn't notice that it already matched there, and return `false` when you call it again.

Comment: I missed that detail in his question. Thanks for correcting me.